# Vue JS, add event handler for elements created within JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am populating a table inside an Axios API call and need to add a delete button to each row.

Im not quite sure how to handle this, in my current experience:

```
formattedVehicles.push([
    "<div class='btn btn-danger' v-on:click='deleteVehicle(id)'>Delete</div>"
]);
```

Ofcourse, this doesn't work. How do I go about getting a click handler for the delete button to take a parametre and handle it as a method?

Comment: Not sure you really understand how vuejs works... you should not be doing this (adding dom nodes in strings to be rendered inside your vue) Take a look a vuejs [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) on how to handle data

Answer (score 6):

In Vue.js you don't have to create div like in jQuery.

Here you have an array of vehicles. The template will update when the array change.

You just need to manage the array of vehicles like this :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      formattedVehicles: [
         { id: 1, name: 'vehi1' },
         { id: 2, name: 'vehi2' },
         { id: 3, name: 'vehi3' }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    callingAxiosApi: function() {
//---> Inside your '.then(function (response) {' you do:
//---> this.formattedVehicles = response; If response is the array of vehicles
    },
    addVehicle: function() {
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 4)) + 4;
      this.formattedVehicles.push({ id: rand, name: 'vehi' + rand });
    },
    deleteVehicle: function(id, index) {
//---> Here you can use 'id' to do an Axios API call.
      this.formattedVehicles.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  <button @click="addVehicle">Add vehicle</button>
  
  <div v-for="(vehicle, index) in formattedVehicles" :key="index">
    id: {{ vehicle.id }}
    <br />
    name: {{ vehicle.name }}
    <button @click="deleteVehicle(vehicle.id, index)">Delete this vehicle</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

To understand the code above :

Use `v-for` when you have a list to show in html :

```
v-for="(anyNameYouWantForItemOfArray, index) in yourArray"
```

Inside the `div` that contains the `v-for` you can access the item of the aray : `{{ vehicle.id }}`, `{{ vehicle.name }}` or pass data in event handler : `@click="deleteVehicle(vehicle.id, index)"`

You must use `key` property in `v-for` since version 2.2.0+ [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for) :

> In 2.2.0+, when using v-for with a component, a key is now required.

To add event handler you just put `v-on:click="method"` or the shortcut `@click="method"`

In this case we put `<button @click="deleteVehicle(vehicle.id, index)">Delete this vehicle</button>` in the `v-for` so when we clicked on the button, we call the `deleteVehicle` method with the index of the row. In your case you can use id to do an API call with axios.

We use the `v-bind` directive to put javascript code in html attribute [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) :

We are in the `v-for` so we have access  to `index` variable :
`v-bind:key="index"` or with the shortcut ':' (a colon) : `:key="index"`